# How to hide a Gtk+ FileChooserDialog in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I have a program set up so that it displays a FileChooserDialog all by itself (no main Gtk window, just the dialog).

The problem I'm having is that the dialog doesn't disappear, even after the user has selected the file and the program has seemingly continued executing.

Here's a snippet that showcases this issue:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class FileChooser():

    def __init__(self):

        global path

        dia = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", None,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.add_filters(dia)

        response = dia.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("Open clicked")
            print("File selected: " + dia.get_filename())
            path = dia.get_filename()
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel clicked")

        dia.destroy()

    def add_filters(self, dia):
        filter_any = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_any.set_name("Any files")
        filter_any.add_pattern("*")
        dia.add_filter(filter_any)

dialog = FileChooser()

print(path)

input()
quit()
```

The dialog only disappears when the program exits with the `quit()` function call.

I've also tried `dia.hide()`, but that doesn't work either - the dialog is still visible while code continues running.

What would the proper way to make the dialog disappear?

**EDIT**: I've since learned that it's discouraged to make a Gtk dialog without a parent window. However, I don't want to deal with having to have the user close a window that has nothing in it and simply stands as the parent for the dialog.

Is there a way to make an invisible parent window and then quit the Gtk main loop when the dialog disappears?

Comment: Shove your `__init__` in an idle callback that calls `Gtk.main_quit()` at the end. You know when the callback is finished when your `Gtk.main()` returns.

Comment: Yes, your real problem is the absence of a main loop. How can GTK+ hide your dialog if the control does not turn back to him?

Comment: @andlabs Could you provide an answer with an example I can try and perhaps mark as answer?

Comment: What do you want to do when the user clicks Cancel? Before I post anything, as it stands, the program will simply crash if you press Cancel because `path` won't be defined.

Comment: @andlabs Well, I'd basically just want it to set path to equal nothing.

Comment: By the way, this is probably not strictly limited to Python 3.4.

Comment: @gauteh No, it wouldn't be. I would just be limited to Gtk 3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up a window first by doing:

```
def __init__ (self):

  [.. snip ..]

  w = Gtk.Window ()

  dia = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", w,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
```

also, set a default value for path in case the user cancels:

```
  path = ''
```

Then, at the end of your script:

```
print (path)

while Gtk.events_pending ():
  Gtk.main_iteration ()

print ("done")
```

to collect and handle all [events](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/functions.html#Gtk.main_iteration).