# How to get a string from the tkinter filedialog in Python 3?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm attempting to use the tkinter `filedialog` to get the user's choice of a file in my Python 3.4 program.

Previously, I was trying to use the Gtk FileChooserDialog, but I keep running into wall after wall getting it to work ([here's my question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980352/how-to-hide-a-gtk-filechooserdialog-in-python-3-4).) So, I (*attempted to*) switched over to tkinter and use the filedialog.

Here's the code I'm using for the GUI:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askopenfile()

print(type(path)) # <- Not actually in the code, but I've included it to show the type
```

It works perfectly, except for the fact that it returns an `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` object instead of a string, like I expected/need it to.

Calling `str()` on that doesn't work, and neither does using the `io` module function `getvalue()`.

Does anyone know how I could get the chosen file path as a string from the `filedialog.askopenfile()` function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure there are several ways, but what about getting `path.name`? This should be a string.

```
print("type(path):", type(path))
# <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>

print("path:", path)
# <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/some/path/file.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

print("path.name:", path.name)
# /some/path/file.txt

print("type(path.name):", type(path.name))
# <class 'str'>
```

Note that `askopenfile` opens and returns the file in read mode by default. If you just want the filename and plan on opening it yourself later, try using `askopenfilename` instead. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150519213847/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) link for more:

> First you have to decide if you want to open a file or just want to get a filename in order to open the file on your own. In the first case you should use tkFileDialog.askopenfile() in the latter case tkFileDialog.askopenfilename().

Comment: Awesome! I had missed that you needed to use `askopenfilename` instead of just `askopenfile`. +1 Accept :)

Comment: I made the same mistake. Thanks!