# Tkinter's askopenfilename() returns weirdness

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to use `filedialog.askopenfile()` to call a function with a normal file path string ('D:/Dropbox/cell-phone-baby.gif') as a parameter, like so:

```
readfile(filedialog.askopenfile())
```

But `filedialog.askopenfile()` returns this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/Dropbox/cell-phone-baby.gif'mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Is there any way to extract the file path as a string from whatever that is, or does anyone maybe know of a better way within Tk to ask for a file path?

I'm using python 3.5, if that's important.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks. And sorry for that, didn't find the other question.

Comment: Actually, I think it's a duplicate of the question [_How to get a string from the tkinter filedialog in Python 3?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990224/how-to-get-a-string-from-the-tkinter-filedialog-in-python-3) question.

Comment: @martineau: maybe. The title mentions "askopenfilename" but the body of the question shows the use of `askopenfile`. Sometimes it's hard to pick a duplicate -- there are often dozens to choose from.